# encode url to fetch JSON data

Tags: android, json

I am trying to fetch json data from remote server. Everything works fine just when a two character string is passed my app gets force stopped. How to encode the url to prevent this error

here is how am trying to fetch json values

```
  jsonobject = JSONfunctions.getJSONfromURL("http://www.example.com/index.php?sutyp="+sutyp);
```

If i pass "Hello" through sutyp there is no error but if i pass "Hello World" app force stops

How do I encode the url to prevent this. Any suggestions would be of great help

Comment: the answer you have marked correct is not the right way to do what you want :)

Comment: Yes and it works perfectly fine. Am using your answer in my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the [`android.net.Uri`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/Uri.html) class:

```
String url = Uri.parse("http://www.example.com/index.php")
                .buildUpon()
                .appendQueryParameter("sutyp", sutyp)
                .build()
                .toString();

jsonobject = JSONfunctions.getJSONfromURL(url);
```

From the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/Uri.html#encode%28java.lang.String%29):

> Encodes characters in the given string as '%'-escaped octets using the
>   UTF-8 scheme. Leaves letters ("A-Z", "a-z"), numbers ("0-9"), and
>   unreserved characters ("_-!.~'()*") intact. Encodes all other
>   characters.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `URLEncoder.encode(string, "utf-8")`

For example

```
String url = String.format("http://www.example.com/index.php?sutyp=%s", sutyp);
jsonobject = JSONfunctions.getJSONfromURL(URLEncoder.encode(url, "utf-8");
```

Here is a reference to the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/URLEncoder.html)